# Why a method scope parameter value is messed up when the same name instance level static field is declared in a class

Tags: c#, .net, clr

```
public class SelfCallingTest
{
    private static int counter;

    public void SelfCallingMethod(int counter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The input integer is: {0} ", counter);

        counter++;

        while (counter <= 2)
        {
            SelfCallingMethod(counter);
        }
    }
}
```

The above SelfCallingTest class has a static field name "counter" and the SelfCallingMethod takes an integer parameter named "counter" (same name as static instance member counter)
SelfCallingMethod is called from console test application Main() method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        SelfCallingTest sct = new SelfCallingTest();
        sct.SelfCallingMethod(0);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Now the problem is that while loop is going in infinite loop because when the value of counter method level variable reaches value = 3 then the thread control is coming out of the method and again resuming while loop execution with method level counter variable getting set to 2 - I am not sure why this counter is set to 2.

As soon as I change the method parameter name counter to other than static instance field name, the results are expected and console is printing 0, 1, 2

Could you please provide me an explanation? Is there a bug in the .NET CLR to read a value from TLS (thread local storage?)

I got what the problem is here, for the initiating callstack for the method SelfCallingMethod, while loop condition is always evaluating 2 ==2 and thats causing the infinite loop.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `if` instead of `while` on your recursive call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is *never using the static field*. Look at this loop:

```
while (counter <= 2)
{
    SelfCallingMethod(counter);
}
```

`counter` is a *local variable* (the parameter). It's then passed by *value* to `SelfCallingMethod`, so that method call isn't going to change it. How would you expect to ever exit the loop, other than via an exception?

So what will happen is you'll get a stack with `SelfCallingMethod(0)`, which calls `SelfCallingMethod(1)` (after the increment) which calls `SelfCallingMethod(2)` which calls `SelfCallingMethod(3)`. That will increment its copy of the counter (to 4) and return... but then the loop from `SelfCallingMethod(2)` will just go round and call `SelfCallingMethod(3)` again. Don't forget that each call of `SelfCallingMethod` has a *separate* `counter` variable.

> As soon as I change the method parameter name counter to other than static instance field name, the results are expected and console is printing 0, 1, 2

Yes, because at that point all the code using `counter` in the method uses the field instead of the local variable. When the names are the same, the local variable *hides* the static variable. (You could still use `SelfCallingTest.counter` to access it explicitly though.)

> Is there a bug in the .NET CLR to read a value from TLS (thread local storage?)

Absolutely not. The only bug is in your code, I'm afraid.

Comment: I got what the problem is here, for the initiating callstack for the method SelfCallingMethod, while loop condition is always evaluating 2 ==2 and thats causing the infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter counter is closest in scope - in fact the static variable is never referenced from your code. There is nothing incrementing the counter that you are testing on.

Comment: I got what the problem is here, for the initiating callstack for the method SelfCallingMethod, while loop condition is always evaluating 2 ==2 and thats causing the infinite loop.